# Yocto: ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND and do_rootfs

Tags: yocto

I have a task which has a dependency set as below:

`bb.build.addtask('do_function2', 'do_build', 'do_rootfs', d)`

There is another task do_function1 that modifies some files in the rootfs:

`ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_append = " do_function1;"`

I require `do_function2` to be triggered only after rootfs for the image has been populated.

Query is whether the tasks that come under `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMANDS_append` satisfy the do_rootfs dependency that I have set up in the `addtask()` call?
I want `do_function2` to run only after `do_function1`. Is that the case even if `do_function1` is specified under `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_append`?

Comment: ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND execution is a part of the do_rootfs task, so the sequence of function invocations will be right for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation. My observations were similar but just wanted to confirm that the documented behavior was also the same.